# Incrementally update date field column based on order of a second column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

MSQL DB for WordPress site.

I would like to update a date column for each row in a table, setting the date/time to an incrementing value (e.g. increment value by 1 day).  The order that I do the updates should be based on the textual sort of another column in the row. The actual date value used isn't relevant (it could start at 2001-01-01 00:00:00 and increment in seconds, minutes, hours or days).

Example of two columns in the table:

```
field_date         , title_text
2014-08-20 09:00:27, AAA-Entry
2014-08-24 10:00:00, ZZZ-Entry
2014-08-27 10:15:00, MMM-Entry
```

So,  the row with the first 'title_text' (alphabetical sorting) should get the newest date.  The next row based on title_text should get a slightly older date and so on until the last row (based on title_text) has the oldest date. So the data shown above would end up looking something like:

```
field_date         , title_text
2000-01-03 00:00:00, AAA-Entry
2000-01-01 00:00:00, ZZZ-Entry
2000-01-02 00:00:00, MMM-Entry
```

After the update then the command:
    select * from tbl_name order by field_date

would show output that would also be in alphabetical order of the title_text field.  This would be equivalent to running:
    select * from tbl_name order by title_text

I'm looking at:
[[Incrementing datetime field with an update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732351/incrementing-datetime-field-with-an-update-statement][1]) for SQL2005 and trying to get this to work on mySQL as I think this would work (I just change the 'order by' statement to 'order by title_text').  But I'm having problems with converting this to mySQL.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on different approaches or with getting the above solution to work in mySQL.

Thanks

Ian

Note: The reason behind this is that Wordpress populates list boxes/search results, based on the posting date, but I want it to be ordered based on the title text.  There *may* be a 'Wordpress' answer (or plugin) to do this (and if you know, please feel free to tell me ;-) ), but from a learning viewpoint, I'd also like to understand how this was possible using mySQL.

Comment: Yes. Just use the Wordpress codex

Comment: Hi Strawberry.  Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I'm spending a lot of time on that site and there is a lot of useful information.  However,  I have yet to find the solution to my problem and I'd rather not be adding plug-ins if possible.  This is why I was looking at the SQL route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do updates with sorts.  The easiest way is to define a variable first and then do the update:

```
set @rn = -1;

update t
    set field_date = date('2000-01-01') + interval (@rn := @rn + 1) day
    order by title_text desc;
```

Comment: Gordan - thanks!  That looks exactly what I'm after.  I'm just having a niggling syntax problem, but now that you've given me the answer, I'll spend some time on it.  Thanks again.  And sorry - not enough Rep to upvote -but you have my thanks!  Ian

Comment: Gordan - all sorted, thanks.  It was just that extra ; after day that threw me.  Thanks again.

Comment: @EyePeaSea . . . That was a typo.

Comment: Sorry - didn't mean that to sound like a criticism.  Just a comment for other SQL Neanderthal like me who might find this thread :-)